# Why isn't my Google Chart displaying?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to dynamically display some `Google Charts` in `HTML` using `JavaScript` and the `Google Chart API` but it doesn't seem to be loading at all.

The page simply displays my text field and nothing else, and even the text field `onblur` event isn't alerting me in the browser.

Below is the code that I am using...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            alert("TEST OUTPUT");
        }

        var chart_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Days',          'Sales',    'Cheeky',   'test'],
          ['19/07/2016',    10,         5,          3],
          ['20/07/2016',    5,          4,          2],
          ['21/07/2016',    15,         3,          1],
          ['22/07/2016',    2,          1,          2]
        ]);

        var startdate = "20/07/2016";
        var enddate = "21/07/2016";
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(load_page_data);


        function load_page_data(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_data.php',
                data: {'startdate':startdate,'enddate':enddate},
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        chart_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        drawChart(chart_data, "My Chart", "Data");
                    }
                },
            });
        }

        function drawChart(chart_data, chart1_main_title, chart1_vaxis_title) {
            var chart1_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);
            var chart1_options = {
                title: chart1_main_title,
                vAxis: {title: chart1_vaxis_title,  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, minValue: 0, gridlines: { color: '#AC935D'} }
                hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
                backgroundColor:{fill: 'transparent'},
                colors: ['#87734A', 'red', 'black'],
            };

            var chart1_chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
            chart1_chart.draw(chart1_data, chart1_options);
        }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#E2C17A">
    <p>Date1: <input type="text" onchange="test()"></p><br/>
    <div id="chart1_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you going to display static data or dynamic data?

Comment: @jnanthak the idea is that I display dynamic data using SQL statements from a database on a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a comma after the `vAxis` key in `chart1_options`

also, you can reference `google.visualization` anywhere in your code,
*but only after* the `load` callback has fired

try setting up your code something like this,
breaking down those long `key: value` pairs will help identify typos

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_data.php',
      data: {
        'startdate': startdate,
        'enddate': enddate
      },
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data){
          drawChart($.parseJSON(data), "My Chart", "Data");
        }
      }
    });

    function drawChart(chart_data, chart1_main_title, chart1_vaxis_title) {
      var chart1_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);
      var chart1_options = {
        title: chart1_main_title,
        vAxis: {
          title: chart1_vaxis_title,
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},
          minValue: 0,
          gridlines: {
            color: '#AC935D'
          }
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Year',
          titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#333'
          }
        },
        backgroundColor: {
          fill: 'transparent'
        },
        colors: ['#87734A', 'red', 'black']
      };

      var chart1_chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
      chart1_chart.draw(chart1_data, chart1_options);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```